# Kruskal's algorithm for the connector problem with pre-assignment

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I am solving the following exercise. Could someone tell me if my algorithm is correct or if there is some more efficient method?

Adapt Kruskal's algorithm to solve the connector problem with pre-assignments: given a connected graph $G$, a set $E'\subseteq E(G)$ and a cost function $c:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+}$, find a connected covering $H$ of $G$ such that $E'\subseteq E(H)$ and $c(H)=\sum_{e\in E(H)}c(e)$ is minimum.

My solution:

1) Define $T:=(V(G),E')$

2) Order $E(G)-E'$ so that $c(e_1)\leq\cdots\leq c(e_m)$

3) for $k$ from $1$ to $m$

if $T+e_k$ has no new cycles then $T=T+e_k$

Comment: I think the usual proof of the correctness of Kruskal's algorithm can be modified to prove your algorithm correct, and so long as you're required to adapt Kruskal I don't see any way to do better. Note that one must assume that $E'$ doesn't have any cycles.

Comment: I don't think we need the assumption that $E'$ is cycle-free @GerryMyerson. Initially when constructing $T = (V(G), E')$ we can contract every connected component to a vertex and then run Kruskal on this graph. This should work. But actually I think also without the contraction your algorithm works because you explicitly stated that you check for "no new cycles" in step 3.

Comment: For a correctness proof it might be easier to consider the algorithm where you contract the connected components after step 1. Because you can then just use Kruskal on the resulting graph and you already know that it will give you a minimum spanning tree. Hence you only have to argue that every solution must consist of the edges in $E'$ plus a spanning tree on the contracted graph.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of ​​contraction it sounds easier to demonstrate that way.
On the other hand, I think that implementing the contraction algorithm is more complicated, right?